# Jquery Chart Plugins

Tags: jquery, json

I want to make charts (bar, pie, scatter line,etc) for my data using jquery chart plugins. I have huge data in the form of JSON. Since I am completely newbie to Jquery and JSON, kindly help me out in this scenario.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Do you know Flot? http://www.flotcharts.org

Comment: No. I am completely new to this scenario. But i need to work out on the same fashion .

Comment: Flot has a really god documentation. Bring yourself a bit into it. We can't do all the work for you. ;)

Comment: Okies .  i just need some hints only, just now checked it. It has very good explanation. Hope this site can be helpful for my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

try highchart http://www.highcharts.com/ and you can find the documentation at http://www.highcharts.com/docs and a good demo for line chart is http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-labels

I hope this help